# Preview increases the size of a tiff file created by epson scanner when manipulating it and saving

Tags: macos, preview, scanning, image-processing

I have an Epson scanner and i have scanned a photo to my mac book pro.

I am running macOS BigSur 11.6.7.

Finder is showing the size of the resulting .tiff file as 6.2mb. I wanted to select a portion of the photo and then create a new .tiff file from the selection.

Here is what I did

1. I opened the scan photo in the preview app.
2. I selected the portion of the image I wanted to create a new file out of.
3. Copy the selected portion.
4. Cmd N, this open a new tab which contains the copied portion of the image.
5. I saved the new file with a different name.

The size of the new file is 30mb.
Now, I was expecting the new file to have a size much smaller than the original.

**What is happening? Why is the new file so big?**

Comment: Perhaps the tiff file as created by the scanner is compressed, and the file Preview created from your selection is not.  Post the output of `file(1)` for both of them.

Answer (score 1):

TIFF images can either be compressed, or uncompressed. Uncompressed images will be `number of pixels` x `bit-depth`, so a 30Mb, 8-bit image is going to be around 5,500 pixels square. *(A 16-bit 30 Mb image will have half the number of pixels, so c. 3,900 square).*

By default, Preview will save without compression. When you Export the image from File > Export, there are options for the compression type, and you can see the effect on file size.

[image]